# Extract public key from host for a Windows

Tags: ssh, rsa

I have username/password to a host and I have successfully logged-in with Putty tool. There are no certificates for the host. How can I exctract the public key for a Windows to use it into known-hosts?
When I use **ssh-keyscan**  in GIT BASH, it nothing shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. The problem was that I forgot to indicate a port in ssh-keyscan.
I have executed the command like `ssh-keyscan -p <port> <host>` in GIT BASH and It helped me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the keys first.

Do that with `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: There is no possibility to create keys for me. It is a 3rdPaty host